# For positive integers $x, y, k$, prove that $4^x (4^y+1)=k(k+1)$ implies $x = y$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In the proof that I read, even $k$ implies $4^x=k$ and $4^y+1=k+1$. I am wondering why we don't need to factorize $4^y+1$ into $pq$, such that $p, q > 1$, and solve for $4^x p=k$, $q=k+1$.

Comment: One of $k$ and $k + 1$ must be even. Whichever one it is must be in $0 \mod 4$. Does that help?

Comment: Suppose $k$ is even. It means that $4^y+1=pq$, such that $p$ and $q$ are odd numbers. Hence, $p$ still can be the factor of $k$ after multiplied by $4^x$. Then, what can I do to find out the $p$ that satisfies this?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're arguing here, so I'll just answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $k^2 < k(k+1) = 4^{x+y}+4^x < (2^{x+y}+2^x)^2$, i.e. $k < 2^{x+y}+2^x$,

and that $(2^{x+y})^2 < 4^{x+y}+4^x = k(k+1) < (k+1)^2$, i.e. $2^{x+y}-1 < k$.

Since $2^x$ divides $4^x(4^y+1)$, either $2^x$ divides $k$, or $2^x$ divides $k+1$.

If $k$ is a multiple of $2^x$, then since $2^{x+y}-1 < k < 2^{x+y}+2^x$, we must have $k = 2^{x+y}$.

Then, $4^{x+y}+4^x = k(k+1) = 2^{x+y}(2^{x+y}+1) = 4^{x+y}+2^{x+y}$. Solving yields $x = y$.

If $k+1$ is a multiple of $2^x$, then since $2^{x+y} < k+1 < 2^{x+y}+2^x+1$, we must have $k+1 = 2^{x+y}+2^x$.

So, $4^{x+y}+4^x = k(k+1) = (2^{x+y}+2^x)(2^{x+y}+2^x+1) = 4^{x+y}+4^x+2^{2x+y+1}+2^{x+y}+2^x$, which is a contradiction since $2^{2x+y+1}+2^{x+y}+2^x > 0$.

Therefore, if $x,y,k$ are positive integers such that $k(k+1) = 4^x(4^y+1)$, then $x = y$.

Comment: Very clear.  In line 3 you have a $2^k$ where you mean $2^x$.  You are really done after line 4...once you know that $k$ is a power of $2$ we get that $k=4^x$ which does the job.

Comment: ^So why don't I need to consider the case where $2^x$ divides $k+1$? It's probably something simple, but I'm missing it.

Comment: No, I'm the one missing something obvious.  Your are correct.  My apologies.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since either $k$ or $k + 1$ is even, and the other is odd, then $k = 4^x$ or $k + 1 = 4^x$. Assuming the latter for sake of contradiction, this implies that $k \equiv -1 \mod 4$, but also that $k = 4^y + 1$. This is a contradiction, so $k = 4^x$.

Therefore $k + 1 = 4^y + 1 = 4^x + 1$, hence $4^x = 4^y \implies x = y$.

Comment: It is clear, as you say, that $4^x$ must divide either $k$ or $k+1$ but why must it equal one or the other?

Comment: The even term could be $4^x$ times an odd factor of $4^{y}+1$.

Comment: Above questions from lulu and N.S. are what I am trying to ask :)